# Incorrect math/rounding?

Tags: java, math, rounding

So in the following set of code, I get completely incorrect answers for some reason...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import type.lib.*;

public class Check03B

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PrintStream print = new PrintStream(System.out);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        print.printf("Enter the satellite altitude in km ... ");
        double A = scan.nextDouble();
        double K = 0.00995;
        double R = 6378;
        double z = (K * (A + R));
        double P = Math.pow(z,(3 / 2));
        double x = (P / 3600);
        double y = (P / 60);
        print.printf("Orbital period = " + x + " hours, " + y + " minutes, and " + "%.1f", P).print(" seconds");
    }
}
```

The answers are suppose to be: 995 hours, 56 minutes, and 21.1 seconds. if the input is 500000

The rounding is not my question, my question is why am I getting:
1.4 hours 83.9 s ... etc.

Comment: Your question seems to be answered, but I'm curious: where did you get this equation for orbital period from?

Comment: @markspace in "Java By Abstraction" Textbook

Comment: If you're interested, [the real formula](http://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Astrodynamics-Dover-Aeronautical-Engineering/dp/0486600610) is a wee bit more complicated, but it's cool to see a text book with some novel problems in it.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is here,

```
double P = Math.pow(z,(3 / 2));
```

More specifically here

```
(3 / 2)
```

because that is integer math. You could use

```
(3 / (double) 2)
```

or

```
(1.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double P = Math.pow(z,(3 / 2)); 
double x = (P / 3600);
double y = (P / 60);
```

3/2 = 1 because its integer

you must use float or double in division